# Libgdx/Java inheritance issue

Tags: java, inheritance, libgdx

I'm currently working on an android project using libgdx and java and have run into an issue that I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I have a base class that extends widget. This base class has a protected member that is set in the act() method of each derived class, but the base statBar class uses the member in its own draw method. Problem is that when the base class method gets called the member is 0 when it should not be. What am I missing?

Base class:

```
public abstract class statBar extends Widget {
  protected Color color;
  protected Color darkColor;
  protected Combatant character;

  protected float currentFillWidth;
  private Drawable fullBar;
  privates Drawable emptyBar;

  public statBar(Color color, Combatant character, Skin skin){
    this.character = character;
    this.color = color;
    this.darkColor = color.cpy().mul(0,0,0,.2f);
    this.fullBar = skin.newDrawable("statBar", this.color);
    this.emptyBar = skin.newDrawable("statBar", this.darkColor);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    float x = getX();
    float y = getY();
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    // draw current fill box
    fullBar.draw(batch, x, y, currentFillWidth, height);

    // if not full, draw empty bar portion
    if (currentFillWidth < width) {
      emptyBar.draw(batch, x+currentFillWidth, y, width-currentFillWidth, height);
    }
  }
}
```

Derived class:

```
public class HealthBar extends statBar {
  public HealthBar(Combatant character, Skin skin) {
    super(Color.RED, character, skin);
  }

  @Override
  public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    currentFillWidth = getWidth() * (character.getCurHP() / character.getMaxHP());
  }
}
```

Finally this is how I'm instantiating the bar, it's added to a larger GUI table on my screen, but really the rest is irrelevant

```
ui.add(new HealthBar(c, skin));
```

c is the current iteration of character in the player's party. Everything displays fine when at full hp, but when your not full, it draws the bar empty. Debugging gives me he fact that when the base class draw method is called, currentFillWidth is once again 0 when it should not be. What am I missing about inheritance that a base class method is not getting updated member values from the derived class?  Libgdx calls act on the widget when I call ui.act in my render method before ui.draw. I have even tried overriding draw in the derived class and forcing a super.draw call. Same results.

Comment: The inheritance seems fine. Maybe getWidth() or getCurHP() return 0.

Comment: I had the libgdx logcat logger output values and everything through derived class act method returns what it's supposed to, and like I said, when hp is full it renders properly so at that point currentFillWidth = width.

Comment: So in the derived class act method I get output like this : bob's hp = 35/40, curFill = 0.  But when hp is full I get curFill of 81.....

Comment: FFS! I got it and feel retarded. Get methods for character was returning int values and apparently without a cast to float it simple dropped the decimals, by casting the returned ints to floats before division, problem solved. 3 hours of pondering due to assumption that as long as the end stored value is a float...currentFillWidth, that Java kept decimals until assignment. *facepalm*

Comment: You didn't end up needing floats right? With integers you just generally multiply first then divide. It's also slightly more efficient to use integers in calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove parenthesis from

```
currentFillWidth = getWidth() * (character.getCurHP() / character.getMaxHP());
```

So

```
currentFillWidth = getWidth() * character.getCurHP() / character.getMaxHP();
```